# Boot diskless client from iscsi target

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iscsi, open-iscsi

I have a Ubuntu server 20.04 setup to run the service as an iscsi target.

I've accessed and mounted the target from a client (running Debian) and installed a Debian on the mounted block/device. Making sure that the first partition on that block started at 2048, for installation of grub.

Having done this along with modifying bios settings to use the same username, password and target name; I get an error connecting to the target when I boot my client.

The reason for this I dont get, because the error I get state that the authentication fails because there is something wrong with the username and password. But they are the same as I used earlier.

Reading multiple guides on howto boot from an iscsi target Ive noticed that a pxe service for booting to the iscsi target, surely I cant need to have that because my bios lets me configure such booting service and thus should support it as a boot option.

Do I need pxe or gpxe to boot from an iscsi target?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was yet again in the documentation regarding the isc dhcp server.
I was able to mount the disk and other boot medias after modifying the dhcp server with the option of "root path" for the requesting client.
However I could not boot from the disk served by the server, Im guessing that the mbr and gruv have gotten misplaced or not in the first 2048-sector on the disk.
Thank you for reading.